# QGraphicsScene crashes PyQt4

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

- Windows XP
- Python 2.7
- PyQt 4

When I run the following code inside the python interactive shell

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
```

python crashes.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `QApplication` first before you can use any of the Qt GUI elements.
Usually it's done like this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
qapp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
...
qapp.exec_()
```

Comment: Yes, instancing QApplication seems to be the key. I wish I understood why this is the case.